# Hide first row of html table 2 having no class and no id attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

i have two html tables in **iframe** tag, having no class nor id attributes.
I am trying to use jQuery to find the second table first row and hide it?
my tables are looks like this:
Note: basically I have two tables, and both the tables are inside the iframe tag. I need to hide the second table first row?

```
<table>
  <tr>
        <td> 1 </td>
         .
         .
         .
 </tr> 
</table>
```

**I need to hide the first row of the following table:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td> This row i need to hide() </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

I have tried too may ways like this:

```
      $( "table[1] tr:first" ).css("display", "none" );
```

but having no results...
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted cf comment (jsfiddle also modified)

See this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/kqj06u2b/) for `$('table').eq(1).find(tr:first').hide();`

As far as I understand (from OPs comment on @DavidThomas' answer) the table resides within an `iframe`. You'll need to get the contents of that frame first, something like

```
    var framebody = $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument.body)
       ,frameSecondTable = framebody.find('table').eq(1);
```

The jsFiddle shows the workings of that.

Comment: Which would hide only first row of every table, not the first row of only the second table.

Comment: @AbdulRahman: Well, I'd suggest not to just copy the code, but study it and adjust to your needs. The jsFiddle contains working code. Furthermore, iframes may be restricted to cross-domain restrictions, so it may not be possible to address the DOM from another domain.

Comment: yes i have tried your jsFiddle code and got my solution. thanks Kooilnc

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest, on the assumption the `<table>` elements aren't siblings:

```
$("table").eq(1).find("tr:first").hide();
```

Solutions using the selector `:nth-child(2)` will only work if the second `<table>` is the second child of its parent, and will select *every* t`<table>` that is the second child of its parent.

Comment: basically i have two tables, and sorry forgotten that both the tables are inside the iframe tag. i need to hide the second table first row?

Comment: Okay, what question is your comment hinting at?

Comment: dear David Thomas, the structure of the tables are looks like this:   <div id="test"> <iframe ........></iframe>  </div>   in the iframe there are two tables where i need to hide second table first row. Your code working fine, but not here in this circumstances.

Comment: Oky can you please tell me how to find the second table in the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $( "table:nth-child(2) tr:first" ).css("display", "none" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child and jQuery hide

```
$( "table:nth-child(2) tr:first" ).hide();
```